# Bootstrap menu drop down animation on click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with drop down animation. I found a great working code but it works on hover event. Now I need some help with tweeking the code that works on "on click" event. Here is my code `https://jsfiddle.net/pLrLLgoj/206/`.

Code:

```
$(function(){
$(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeIn("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeOut("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
        });
});
```

Comment: You don't want the animation on hover?

Comment: I want on certain screen size, but when i resize it to a smaller size, its not a smart option.

Comment: Just detect mobile deive and unbind hover and bind it with click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check **[I modified your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/pLrLLgoj/211/)**

I've removed JS, changed only CSS to animate the dropdown on click

```
.dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform-origin: top;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
.open .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform-origin: top;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```